# убрать класс если он есть

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

Привет всем помогите пожалуйста новичку...
вот такой код

мне нужно чтобы вторая часть срабатывала при клике на body при условии что боковое меню с классом active

```
$('body').on('click', '.hamburger', function(e){
$('.hamburger').addClass('hamburger_active');
$('.header__menu').addClass('header__menu_active');
 });
$('body').on('click',function(e){
$('.hamburger').removeClass('hamburger_active');
$('.header__menu').removeClass('header__menu_active');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есть ли у элемента класс можно узнать с помощью функции [hasClass()](https://basicweb.ru/jquery/jquery_method_hasclass.php)

```js
$('body').on('click','.hamburger', function(e){
  if ($('.hamburger').hasClass('hamburger_active')) {
    $('.hamburger').removeClass('hamburger_active');
    $('.header__menu').removeClass('header__menu_active');
  } else {
    $('.hamburger').addClass('hamburger_active');
    $('.header__menu').addClass('header__menu_active');
  }
});
```

```css
.hamburger_active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hamburger">hamburger</div>
```

Так же можно укоротить функцию используя [toggleClass()](https://basicweb.ru/jquery/jquery_method_toggleclass.php)

```js
$('body').on('click', '.hamburger', function(e){
    var hasNotClass = !$('.hamburger').hasClass('hamburger_active');
    $('.hamburger').toggleClass('hamburger_active', hasNotClass);
    $('.header__menu').toggleClass('header__menu_active', hasNotClass);
});
```

```css
.hamburger_active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hamburger">hamburger</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!